# is there a method to skip unconvertible rows when casting a pandas series from str to float?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas datagframe created from a csv file. One column of this dataframe contains numeric data that is initially cast as a string. Most entries are numeric-like, but some contain various error codes that are non-numeric. I do not know beforehand what all the error codes might be or how many there are. So, for instance, the dataframe might look like:

```
[In 1]: df
[Out 1]:
            data     OtherAttr
MyIndex
0           1.4        aaa
1           error1     foo
2           2.2        bar
3           0.8        bar
4           xxx        bbb
...
743733      BadData    ccc
743734      7.1        foo
```

I want to cast `df.data` as a float and throw out any values that don't convert properly. Is there a built-in functionality for this? Something like:

```
df.data = df.data.astype(float, skipbad = True)
```

(Although I know that specifically will not work and I don't see any kwargs within astype that do what I want)

I guess I could write a function using `try` and then use pandas `apply` or `map`, but that seems like an inelegant solution. This must be a fairly common problem, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) method which "attempts to infer better dtype for object columns":

```
In [11]: df['data'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[11]: 
0    1.4
1    NaN
2    2.2
3    0.8
4    NaN
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

In fact, you can apply this to the entire DataFrame:

```
In [12]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[12]: 
         data OtherAttr
MyIndex                
0         1.4       aaa
1         NaN       foo
2         2.2       bar
3         0.8       bar
4         NaN       bbb
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just what I was looking for. One minor follow-up point: if you have a mix of types already in a column (some float, some string) then `convert_objects` will fail silently. Of course, the reasonable response to that is "don't have a mix of object types in one column!"

Comment: _"FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric."_